# SQL Server 2008 Database (How to lock it from copying and attach it in another machine)

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2008

I have a database with data that i don't want anyone to copy around.

Now, how can i prevent other users to have access in the local machine, but whenever i want to work with, i am allowed.

And another issue I'm thinking, how can i lock the DB so if someone copy the .mdb file and try to attach it on another machine he/she couldn't see a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different kinds of encryption options available in SQL Server.   If you don't want to have to re-write your application then the new feature in SQL Server 2008 called **Transparent Data Encryption (TDE)** is for you. It means you can encrypt the data files to prevent unauthorized users getting at the data from a backup or by copying the data files.

This [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx) should be enough to get you started.

Comment: I think this could work, I'll get this in depth soon...Thank you Niko :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use database encryption to achieve this.  Then the mdb file will be useless.

Some links

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510663.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316898

Comment: any useful link-tutorial on how to do this please?

Comment: this encryptions are in database field and datatype level, i don't like this..thank you though you were enlightening.

Comment: huh?  from the first link: `There are two different kinds of encryptions available in SQL Server: Database Level – This level secures all the data in a database...`  So what did you read?